# How to debug C program on microcontroller

Tags: c, crash, serial-port, microcontroller

this is my first C code. So, I wrote a code which gets values from 5  potentiometers from a microcontroller(pololu maestro) via serial port and then moves 10 servos from the 5 pot values. When I compile and run the code in CodeBlocks, there are no errors or warnings, but when I run it crashes. It says that my .exe file has stopped running.

```
// Uses POSIX functions to send and receive data from a Maestro.
// NOTE: The Maestro's serial mode must be set to "USB Dual Port".
// NOTE: You must change the 'const char * device' line below.

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#define O_NOCTTY 0
#else
#include <termios.h>
#endif

// Gets the position of a Maestro channel.
// See the "Serial Servo Commands" section of the user's guide.
int maestroGetPosition(int fd, unsigned char channel)
{
  unsigned char command[] = {0x90, channel};
  if(write(fd, command, sizeof(command)) == -1)
  {
    perror("error writing");
    return -1;
  }

  unsigned char response[2];
  if(read(fd,response,2) != 2)
  {
    perror("error reading");
    return -1;
  }

  return response[0] + 256*response[1];
}

// Sets the target of a Maestro channel.
// See the "Serial Servo Commands" section of the user's guide.
// The units of 'target' are quarter-microseconds.
int maestroSetTarget(int fd, unsigned char channel, unsigned short target1, unsigned short target2, unsigned short target3, unsigned short target4, unsigned short target5, unsigned short target6, unsigned short target7, unsigned short target8, unsigned short target9, unsigned short target10)
{
  unsigned char command[] = {170, 12, 31, 10, channel, target1 & 0x7F, target1 >> 7 & 0x7F, target2 & 0x7F, target2 >> 7 & 0x7F, target3 & 0x7F, target3 >> 7 & 0x7F, target4 & 0x7F, target4 >> 7 & 0x7F, target5 & 0x7F, target5 >> 7 & 0x7F, target6 & 0x7F, target6 >> 7 & 0x7F, target7 & 0x7F, target7 >> 7 & 0x7F, target8 & 0x7F, target8 >> 7 & 0x7F, target9 & 0x7F, target9 >> 7 & 0x7F, target10 & 0x7F, target10 >> 7 & 0x7F};
  if (write(fd, command, sizeof(command)) == -1)
  {
    perror("error writing");
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
  // Open the Maestro's virtual COM port.
  const char * device = "\\\\.\\COM8";  // Windows, "\\\\.\\COM6" also works
  //const char * device = "/dev/ttyACM0";  // Linux
  //const char * device = "/dev/cu.usbmodem00034567"; // Mac OS X
  int fd = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
  if (fd == -1)
  {
    perror(device);
    return 1;
  }

#ifndef _WIN32
  struct termios options;
  tcgetattr(fd, &options);
  options.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
  options.c_oflag &= ~(ONLCR | OCRNL);
  tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
#endif

int count1;
int b_pos;
int b_l;
int x[10];
int rel;
int count2;
int count3;
int count4;
int x0[10];
int x1;
int x2;
int x3;
int x4;
int x5;

for (count1=1; count1<=1000; count1++){

    x1 = maestroGetPosition(fd, 0);
    x2 = maestroGetPosition(fd, 1);
    x3 = maestroGetPosition(fd, 2);
    x4 = maestroGetPosition(fd, 3);
    x5 = maestroGetPosition(fd, 4);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if(x1 == 0){
        b_pos = 0;
    }else if( (x1 <= 102) && (x1 > 0) ){
        b_pos = 1;
    }else if( (x1 <= 102) && (x1 > 0) ){
        b_pos = 2;
    }else if( (x1 <= 102) && (x1 > 0) ){
        b_pos = 3;
    }else if( (x1 <= 102) && (x1 > 0) ){
        b_pos = 4;
    }else if( (x1 <= 102) && (x1 > 0) ){
        b_pos = 5;
    }else if( (x1 <= 102) && (x1 > 0) ){
        b_pos = 6;
    }else if( (x1 <= 102) && (x1 > 0) ){
        b_pos = 7;
    }else if( (x1 <= 102) && (x1 > 0) ){
        b_pos = 8;
    }else if( (x1 <= 102) && (x1 > 0) ){
        b_pos = 9;
    }else if( (x1 <= 102) && (x1 > 0) ){
        b_pos = 10;
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if(b_pos != 0){
        if (x2 <= 255){
            b_l = 1;
        }else if( (x2 <= 510) && (x2 >= 256) ){
            b_l = 2;
        }else if( (x2 <= 765) && (x2 >= 511) ){
            b_l = 3;
        }else{
            b_l = 4;
        }
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    x3 = (x3*0.988)+992;
    for (count4 = 1; count4 <= 10; count4++){
        x[count4] = x3;
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if(b_pos != 0){
        x4 = (x4*0.39)-200;
        x5 = (x5*0.098);
        x[b_pos] = x[b_pos] + x4;
        rel = 1;

        if (x4 >= 0){
            for (count2 = b_pos; count2<=( (b_pos) + (b_l) ); count2++){
                        if ((count2 > 0) && (count2 < 11)){
                            x[count2] = x[count2] + x4  + ( (x4/abs(x4))*(x5*rel) );
                            rel += 1;
                        }
            }
            for (count2 = b_pos; count2<=( (b_pos) - (b_l) ); count2--){
                        if ((count2 > 0) && (count2 < 11)){
                            x[count2] = x[count2] + x4  + ( (x4/abs(x4))*(x5*rel) );
                            rel += 1;
                        }
            }
        }
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    for (count3 = 1; count3 <= 10; count3++){
        if (x[count3] < 992){
            x[count3] = 992;
        }
        if (x[count3] > 2000){
            x[count3] = 2000;
        }
        x0[count3] = (x[count3] * 4);
    }


  //int target = (position < 6000) ? 7000 : 5000;
  //printf("Setting target to %d (%d us).\n", target, target/4);
  maestroSetTarget(fd, 7, x0[1], x0[2], x0[3], x0[4], x0[5], x0[6], x0[7], x0[8], x0[9], x0[10]);

}

return 0;

close(fd);

}
```

Comment: `script`? Wow....:-)

Comment: you run the code in CodeBlocks on your PC? do you have an emulator for the microcontroller? if not, i doubt that you will be bale to test.run your code on your PC. you will have to run it on the microcontroller. you may also want to read about how to debug your code on the microcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
x[b_pos] = x[b_pos] + x4;
```

where `b_pos` could have a value of `10`, but `x` can only hold `10` elements, accessing then `11`th element causes undefined behavior which in turn could make your program crash.

Comment: Ok so I changed the size to 11 and it still crashes. Guys got any suggestions??

Comment: I am not surprised, I suggest using a debugger, if you don't know how, there is plenty of material online.